# forever run for node.js using jenkins on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, jenkins, forever, forever-monitor

I am trying to run a forever command for a node.js script to run it in background. My complete command is

```
"C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/npm/forever.cmd" -c "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" start app.js
```

This works fine when I ran it on command prompt directly. However when i put it as build step in jenkins I always get the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\apps>"C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/npm/forever.cmd" -c "C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" start app.js 
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
```

PATH on the machine is correctly set and include path to the node application. This is confirmed as command runs successfully when run locally on the slave machine without giving absolute path.  Also I have provide the path to node executable in the command itself using -c option in case it does not pick up from PATH variable.

Not sure if this may be because jenkins run things on window using JVM client?

Any suggestion to resolve this.

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Are you using forever-win https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-win ?

Comment: I am using forever installed using npm install forever -g command on windows. As the command runs fine when running locally on windows machine, I dont see issue with forever package. Issue seems to be with how jenkins drives this command on windows. As forever itself call node inside it, wondering is some configuration is required at jenkins level (in JVM client with Jenkins runs to connect to window machine. )

Comment: The issue is still that of `PATH`. Jenkins may be not running under the same user as your local logged in user (that you tried command line tests on). Do a simple test: trigger a build that only has "Execute Windows Batch Command" build step, and there write only `set`. This will print all environment variables. Verify they are all correct and path is set correctly there.

Comment: I am using the same user for jenkins. However you are right, with your test, I can see the difference between the PATH jenkins takes and the one I set locally. I am not sure how and from where Jenkins is taking this PATH value. Trying to update Jenkins and restart it.

Comment: You mentioned a slave. It's the slave process then, not the main Jenkins that should be restarted and using the same username.

Comment: yes its slave. Jenkins use the slave to run the tests. so I need to provide the access details to jenkins for log in. I can also login to slave myself and run things manually.

Comment: Anyway its started working once I restarted the slave, removed and added the slave node again in jenkins.

Comment: See the answer below why restarting the slave was the important part

Answer (score 1):

Changes to `PATH` (such as those done after installing software like `node`) are not picked up by processes that were already running at the time of installation.

These processes (Jenkins process, and the Slave processes on remote machines, in this case) need to be restarted after the installation, in order to inherit the newly modified `PATH`.

When you test by login in remotely and running commands manually, your login session command prompt is newly created, thus inherits the new `PATH` and your tests work, however a Jenkins Slave process that hasn't been restarted since the installation will not have the new `PATH`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are right. Slave agent need to be restarted. While this problem is solved. I have end up in another problem. Now forever start correctly though seems like does not show the forever processes when FOREVER LIST command is run. Also forever stopall says no forever process is running. Seems like some bug in forever for windows. Trying to see how to resolve.